# Converter string de data em data

Tags: python-3.x, data

Preciso converter a data do formato 'Aug 29, 2019' para 06/08/2019 porem não estou conseguindo com o strptime, Segue o erro.

ValueError: time data 'Aug 29, 2019' does not match format ' %m %d, %Y'

Comment: Não entendo o porquê dos votos negativas nas peguntas aqui no SO

Comment: Partilho do seu questionamento, alguns parecem que já nasceram sabendo tudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar o `datetime.strptime` para isso, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import datetime
dataString = 'Aug 29, 2019'
dataObj = datahora = datetime.datetime.strptime(dataString,'%b %d, %Y')
print(dataObj.date())
#E pode formatar a saída do jeito que achar melhor
print(dataObj.date().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```